# Cisco CVP Integration with Custom Modify Element

Tags: java, customization, cisco, ivr

I have one external Project in Cisco CVP, i have imported that project into the Cisco CVP IDE. This project has some custom Element, i have their related classes as well. I have placed their related classes in the cisco\cvp\plugin\commin library as well as in the deploy\application\java\classes folder as well but still my custom element are showing an error ..Can any body has any idea how to overcome this.  i have placed the screen shot as well.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Copy the jar files to the path

C:\Cisco\CallStudio\eclipse\plugins\com.audiumcorp.studio.library.common_x.x.x.-SNAPSHOT\lib

and then restart the Call Studio IDE

Answer (score 1):

Copy the same jar in the below location as well ans try 
C:\Cisco\CallStudio\eclipse\plugins\com.audiumcorp.studio.elements.core_9.0.1-SNAPSHOT\lib

Answer (score 0):

I find it's best to drop the class files in to CS directly. Custom elements like this go into /deploy/java/application/. Also note that any packages used in the class file are required subdirectories(folders) here.

You don't need to restart Call Studio to register the new class files. You just need to close and reopen the main app.callflow file.

Good luck!